# Convert Paradox to MDB

Tags: delphi, ms-access, paradox

I need to access an database in DB (paradox) files. I'm in a project that will be used Delphi and Access (i know it's very old but the customer want this) and the old project use paradox database.

I would like to know, if is there any program to convert Paradox (DB Files) to MDB (to be accessed by ms access) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I once did Paradox to Access conversion successfully using the Delphi code that I found on this page:

http://delphi.about.com/od/database/l/aa062601a.htm

Comment: The benefit of a Delphi data pump solution is that you might find you need more than a direct copy; Some transformation might be required, or some filtering.  For example, there may be some obsolete data in the old model, or there might be new fields in the new model, that you might need, or there might be a datatype that you have a hard time directly translating. Paradox had a few field types that I think might not have 1:1 direct equivalents in Access.

Comment: @Warren P: You are right, I had to make some customizations. I could not directly convert Paradox autoincrement fields to Access AutoInc because that would create new primary key values that doesn't match detail tables. Also Access does not allow blank values as primary key and I had to work around that. So I agree it is definitely useful to be able to make adjustments to the conversion using code.

Answer (score 3):

Paradox itself can do it: use an ODBC binding to your MDB file, then export from Paradox to the MDB.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Paradox Data Editor http://www.mitec.cz/pde.html